# Error when implementing Facebook login button for Android

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am trying to implement the login with Facebook feature for my next Android app. I have gone thru the tutorial from Facebook development website. Everything seems okay. However, once I implemented this following code:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvLoginRegister"/>
```

When I compiled, the following error displayed:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
        at com.myapp.myapp.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: null
        at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:99)
        at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getCallbackRequestCodeOffset(FacebookSdk.java:735)
        at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.toRequestCode(CallbackManagerImpl.java:109)
        at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<clinit>(LoginButton.java:58)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            atandroid.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.myapp.myapp.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:26)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Has anyone face with this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you declared these class and provider in your manifest file?


<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
              android:configChanges=
                     "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />

and provider 

 <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:exported="true" />

Comment: yes I already did it in my AndroidManifest file. Any other suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using the facebook sdk 4.0. Here are some tips:
1) Manifest stuff:
Make sure that you have this activity declared in your manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

And the facebook meta as child of the application tag:

```
<!-- App id for Facebook login -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

2) Assuming that you have a `CallbackManager` instance to know when the user finished the login
Did you instantiated it in the `onCreate` like this?

```
mCallback = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

Did you call it in in the `onActivityResult`? (Remember that if this is in a `Fragment` you must invoke the `onActivityResult` of the Fragment's instance in the Activity `onActivityResult` method explicity)

3) Finally, are you using some gradle dependency like this `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:+'`?. If not, try it.

Let me know if this did help you. If not, I will ask you some more feedback/code about this issue.

**UPDATE:**

In your xml layout, do you have this attribute in the xml parent (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`, etc.)?

`xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

In my xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_login"
        facebook:confirm_logout="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actually I haven't implemented anything in the Activity.java file. I just add the xml to the layout file and compile to see the result and it immediately display error.

Comment: Why don't you try? in some point or another you'll need to know if the user has loged in with fb or not, right? Maybe the issue is coming from that side. BTW are you using the gradle dependency or not?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how I have my xml. The only thing different is that attribute in my `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this error you mentioned, not only in my own Application, but also when using the Scrumptious demo application included in the 4.1.0 SDK.

If you load the sample 4.1.0 Android SDK projects, and load the splash.mxl view belonging to the Scrumptious Demo project, the Login button does not show and gives the same error.

Fortunately, this issue only occurs in the IDE, not in a compiled Application. My 'Answer' would be to ignore this issue, and treat it as an SDK problem. Hopefully it will be addressed in the next SDK update. You can still use the button, however it won't render in design view.

Alternatively, you could try and use an older version of the SDK, however I've attempted that (4.0.1 and 4.0.0) to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In the build.gradle file and inside "dependencies" bracket, I added this line

**compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'**.

Then, it works for me.